# IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 in activity

Tags: android

When running my app on a tablet rather then on a phone (which I've never tried before) I get this stack trace when I start a certain activity. I have looked through the .xml files of that activity to look for anything that might be 0 at runtime, and replaced everything that came to mind (like for example `?attr/actionBarSize`) but it didn't change anything. My biggest problem: **The stack trace is too long to get to the origin of the exception**. Any ideas how I can find my mistake?
PS: I don't know of any Bitmap in that activity, which makes it even more confusing

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0                                                                        
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:933)                                                                           
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912)                                                                         
     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)                                                                       
     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawable.java:711) 
     at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:278)
     at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:76)
     at android.widget.ExpandableListView.dispatchDraw(ExpandableListView.java:460)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16272)
     at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:5983)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16272)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.drawChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1127)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1369)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16272)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15187)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15990)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3708)
     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3502)
     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16272)
     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:3047)
     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15192)
     at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15215)
     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:307)
     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:313)
     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:352)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2815)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2638)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2226)
     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootIm
```

Well, and here are my depenencies from gradle, I'm now using the 24 support libraries but the error persist...

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    wearApp project(':wear')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1208.jre7'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

And here comes the .xml code for the activity that crashes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="org.pbdevelopement.cineapp.SpielplanActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_spielplan">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/spielplan_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/Grey600"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_selector_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout XML and the activity code?

Comment: @MobileDeveloper added the xml, what part of the activity code are you interested in? It is quite a bunch....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you may be using the support library? I had the same error and traced it to a bug with DrawableCompat.wrap() in 23.4.0 that doesn't exist in earlier & later versions of the support library. This bug incorrectly sets the drawable bounds to 0 (or negative in the case of an inset drawable). I've seen this cause a crash on Android 5.1.

I didn't see a specific issue opened for this, but looking at the code for DrawableWrapperDonut/DrawableWrapperGingerbread, I can see that the problem was introduced around 23.4.0 and later fixed, so if you were using the buggy version, switching to a good version should fix this crash.

Comment: Thanks, that might be the reason. Unfortunately I can't get ahold of that tablet anymore, but I'll be sure to try it out... Gather your points for now ;)

Comment: Well, this was not the cause :/ Check my question edit for the dependencies, I have them all up to date now (though Android Studio thinks it's a bad idea to have the 24 version when I'm still targeting and compiling in 23... Is it a problem?)

Comment: You were somewhat right though, it only happens on lollipop, works fine in kitkat and marshmallow...

Comment: Hmm... yeah in my case in was a combination of a support library bug and a Lollipop bug. The way I figured out the cause was by checking calls to setBounds. You could also try to put a breakpoint inside that line of Bitmap.java where the exception is thrown (make sure you select the right SDK for the version of Android you're running on so the breakpoint matches up!), to see *which* view is triggering the exception. That might help you to trace the cause.

Comment: For your comment about targeting/compiling in 23, I've seen that warning before but I haven't seen it since upgrading to Android Studio 2.2. I couldn't find this limitation officially documented anywhere else and the APK seems to run fine even though I target 23, so would be interesting to know if this was just a faulty warning or what the cause of that is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have solved the problem, but it is also left for later people.

If you use `<inset>` drawable leading an abnormality or crash on Android 5.1, you should try use `<layer-list>` drawable to instead of , it works for me. The drawable is normal display.