# InsetDrawable not working on API 21 - why?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm using the following code in my Android App:

```
InsetDrawable id = new InsetDrawable(context.getDrawable(drawableId), 150, 200, 150, 400);
imageView.setImageDrawable(id);
```

It works fine on newer Android API Levels, however on API 21 (the lowest I want to support) this happens and the app crashes:

```
08-02 09:39:26.657 30728-30728/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.app, PID: 30728
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:933)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:912)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:879)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createCachedBitmapIfNeeded(VectorDrawable.java:711)
    at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.draw(VectorDrawable.java:278)
    at android.graphics.drawable.InsetDrawable.draw(InsetDrawable.java:220)
    at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1187)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16219)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15139)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15940)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3703)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15940)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3703)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15134)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15162)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15940)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3703)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3497)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16222)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2932)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15139)
    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:15162)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:275)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:320)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2751)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2584)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1191)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6642)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
```

It seems that it is a bug in either the Android Support Library or a bug in this specific API Level, as discussed here: [IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 in activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980595/illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-in-activity)

Is there an alternative to `InsetDrawable` or some workaround for API 21?